# How do I replace a color with pure white?

Tags: pixelmator

I have a simple image with an off-white background.  I would like to make that off-white background be pure white.  I can use the "Replace Color" tool to select the off-white but I don't know how to then get that selected color to be set to my desired color of pure white.

Answer (score 0):

In CMYK mode go to Curves and pull the lefthand slider along. Check the off white areas (now hopefully white) with the eye-dropper tool and keep dragging along until the eye-dropper registers 0 colours. You shouldn't need to drag it far (a few points) and beware as it will alter some other colours slightly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to accomplish this, but if it's just a background that's all around an image, this might be easiest:

Select the Magic Wand tool. Set the Tolerance to 2. Select the "Contiguous" option.
Click the background. It should be completely selected, with nothing inside the image selected.
Choose Edit > Fill. Select Contents: White; Mode: Normal; Opacity: 100%. Click OK.

[image: Image with offwhite background]

[image: Background selected with magic wand]

[image: Fill dialog box]

[image: Background replaced with white]

Be aware that "white" is really no color. If you select the entire background and delete it, that is technically white for printing or display -- most programs including web browsers show the absence of color as white.

(People usually ask about how to get rid of a white background, and that is more complicated).

The only problem you can have is if there is a white part of the image that touches the background. In that case, you have to do something to limit the selection to just the background, not the white part of the image.